# Reading/Writing To Serial Port Not Working

Tags: command-line, serial-port

I am attempting to pass data through my serial port and see the result. I have added myself to the group for /dev/ttyS0 and run

```
cat < /dev/ttyS0
```

on one terminal for reading of data. To write I tried

```
echo -e '123' > /dev/ttyS0
```

The commands don't throw any errors, but I don't see any output on the first terminal. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the loop-back connection/jumper. The serial port send data through pin 3 and receive them through pin 2.

As you are using same port, connect 2 ↔ 3 with a wire.

**Reference:** [Wikipedia: Loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Serial_interfaces)

Comment: That may be an option I can try, but I was hoping that I can intercept the data or progmatically set it up to send to itself or another serial device without needing cables and such. Is this even possible?

Comment: @MrJman006, No, that is not possible for real serial port (It has separate FIFO's for Input and Output with separate send & receive physical lines). Not the same as network interfaces, because port are logical and there is always virtual loopback interface setup by default (try: `ifconfig -a`, see `lo`)